Numpy implementation of Matern covariance kernel derivative
For my research, I'm making use of the Numpy implementation of the Matern covariance kernel.
To make sure I'm understanding what's happening, I try to derive the formulas inside the Numpy implementation myself.
For example, let's consider the $\nu=2.5$ anisotropic matern kernel in two dimensions:
$$K(x,y)=(1+d+\frac{d^2}{3})\exp(-d)$$
with
$$d=\sqrt{5}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^2 \left(\frac{x_i-y_i}{l_i}\right)^2}.$$
Now I want to compute the gradient with respect to the length scales for hyper parameter optimization purpuses. So, I compute:
$$
\partial_{l_i} K(x,y)=\frac{5}{3}\exp(-d)\left( 1 + d \right)\frac{(x_i-y_i)^2}{l_i^3}
$$
(computed using the following bit of Mathematica)
d = Sqrt[((x1 - y1)/l1)^2 + ((x2 - y2)/l2)^2]*Sqrt[5]
FullSimplify[
  D[Exp[-d]*(1 + d + d^2/3), 
   l1]] /. {Sqrt[5] Sqrt[(x1 - y1)^2/l1^2 + (x2 - y2)^2/l2^2] -> tmp}

So far, so good. Now, I take a look at the Numpy implementation (Lines 1729-1752 in kernels.py):

            # We need to recompute the pairwise dimension-wise distances
            if self.anisotropic:
                D = (X[:, np.newaxis, :] - X[np.newaxis, :, :]) ** 2 / (
                    length_scale**2
                )
            else:
                D = squareform(dists**2)[:, :, np.newaxis]

            if self.nu == 0.5:
                denominator = np.sqrt(D.sum(axis=2))[:, :, np.newaxis]
                divide_result = np.zeros_like(D)
                np.divide(
                    D,
                    denominator,
                    out=divide_result,
                    where=denominator != 0,
                )
                K_gradient = K[..., np.newaxis] * divide_result
            elif self.nu == 1.5:
                K_gradient = 3 * D * np.exp(-np.sqrt(3 * D.sum(-1)))[..., np.newaxis]
            elif self.nu == 2.5:
                tmp = np.sqrt(5 * D.sum(-1))[..., np.newaxis]
                K_gradient = 5.0 / 3.0 * D * (tmp + 1) * np.exp(-tmp)


And we observe much of the same terms, we replace $d$ by tmp. However, where my analytical computation have a $\frac{(x_i-y_i)^2}{l_i^3}$ term, the numpy implementation appears to have a $\frac{(x_i-y_i)^2}{l_i^2}$ term (via the definition of D on top of the code snippet above).
It seems highly unlikely that the numpy implementation is wrong, so can anybody explain me where I went wrong?
Many thanks in advance!
